# How to properly read/write java.util.Date with JDBC

Tags: java, date, jdbc, timestamp

i'm trying to store and load a java.util.Date with JDBC

it is stored like this

```
insertStmt.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
```

and read like that

```
ResultSet q;
Assert.assertEquals(t.getTime().getTime(), q.getTimestamp("time").getTime());

java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<1392378420194> but was:<1392378420193>
```

where is that millisecond?

my database is postgres and the fieldd is "timestamp without time zone"

EDIT:
this question can be closed, because storing/retrieving seems to be ok, the problem is that i'm loading the wrong lines from the database

Comment: Could be a precision issue with the underlying datatype that stores time on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can do one thing, if milliseconds does matter to you, try converting it to actual time string and then compare. You need to extract date from long ms value as well.

```
package com.date;

public class CovertFromLong {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long ms = 1392378420194L;
        long sec = (ms / 1000) % 60;
        long min = (ms / (1000 * 60)) % 60;
        long hr = (ms / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24;
        System.out.println(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d:%d", hr, min, sec, ms));
    }
}
```